# Proc causing a random TypeError

Tags: ruby

I'm refactoring some code and this `proc` is causing an error randomly and I don't know why or how to debug it... Any ideas?

## New code with `proc`

```
  defense_moves, offense_moves = [], []
  determine_move = ->move,side,i { side << move.count(move[i]) }
  defense.size.times { |i| determine_move.(defense, defense_moves, i) }
  offense.size.times { |i| determine_move.(offense, offense_moves, i) }
  dm = defense[defense_moves.index(defense_moves.max)].nil? ? [0] : defense[defense_moves.index(defense_moves.max)]
  om = offense[offense_moves.index(offense_moves.max)].nil? ? [0] : offense[offense_moves.index(offense_moves.max)]
```

## Original code:

```
  d = 0
  defense_moves = []
  loop do 
    defense_moves << defense.count(defense[d])
    break if defense.count(defense[d]).zero?
    d += 1
  end

  o = 0
  offense_moves = []
  loop do 
    offense_moves << offense.count(offense[o])
    break if offense.count(offense[o]).zero?
    o += 1
  end

  dm = defense[defense_moves.index(defense_moves.max)].nil? ? [0] : defense[defense_moves.index(defense_moves.max)]
  om = offense[offense_moves.index(offense_moves.max)].nil? ? [0] : offense[offense_moves.index(offense_moves.max)]
```

## TypeError

```
ttt2.rb:95:in `[]': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)
    from ttt2.rb:95:in `computer_make_move'
    from ttt2.rb:133:in `draw_board'
    from ttt2.rb:24:in `place'
    from ttt2.rb:209:in `block in start_new_game'
    from ttt2.rb:188:in `loop'
    from ttt2.rb:188:in `start_new_game'
    from ttt2.rb:199:in `block in start_new_game'
    from ttt2.rb:188:in `loop'
    from ttt2.rb:188:in `start_new_game'
    from ttt2.rb:199:in `block in start_new_game'
    from ttt2.rb:188:in `loop'
    from ttt2.rb:188:in `start_new_game'
    from ttt2.rb:199:in `block in start_new_game'
    from ttt2.rb:188:in `loop'
    from ttt2.rb:188:in `start_new_game'
    from ttt2.rb:199:in `block in start_new_game'
    from ttt2.rb:188:in `loop'
    from ttt2.rb:188:in `start_new_game'
    from ttt2.rb:234:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What is `defense` and `offence`? It's simple arrays? Of string?

Comment: You didn't perform this `break if defense.count(defense[d]).zero? ; d += 1` condition, thats why i doesn't work, i think.

Comment: Why would you need that in a proc? It's not a loop. Don't need a break statement...

Comment: They are multidimensional arrays

Comment: Because of that break, you added `0` in `defense/offence_moves` (last position), perhaps this made work you code.

Comment: You have a point .. good catch .. I will test that later. That is probably the reason. Good job bro.

Comment: I added an answer that fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, before code was that:

```
defense_moves, offense_moves = [], []
determine_move = -> move, side, i { side << move.count(move[i]) }
(defense.size + 1).times { |i| determine_move.(defense, defense_moves, i) }
(offense.size + 1).times { |i| determine_move.(offense, offense_moves, i) }
dm = defense[defense_moves.index(defense_moves.max)].nil? ? [0] : defense[defense_moves.index(defense_moves.max)]
om = offense[offense_moves.index(offense_moves.max)].nil? ? [0] : offense[offense_moves.index(offense_moves.max)]
```

`(defense/offence.size + 1)`, cause break was after adding to array.

I'm not sure was it proper or not, but i guess it works the same as that loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
loop do 
  defense_moves << defense.count(defense[d])
  ...
end
```

is guaranteed to assign at least one element to defense_moves

```
determine_move = ->move,side,i { side << move.count(move[i]) }
defense.size.times { |i| determine_move.(defense, defense_moves, i) }
```

provides no such guarantee. Hence `defense_moves.max` and `defense_moves.index(defense_moves.max)` are both nil which is generating your error.

Answer (score -1):

Your error message means that you're passing nil to the `[]` method. I would guess it's in this line

```
defense[defense_moves.index(defense_moves.max)]
```

or the other similar one.

if `defense_moves` is an empty array, `[].max #=> nil` and then if you pass `defense[nil]` you would receive that error.

Comment: Both code blocks have the same nil check only the proc version fails.

Comment: defense[defense_moves.index(defense_moves.max)].nil? is only checking if the value of the array index is nil. 
defense_moves.index(defense_moves.max) this code is returning nil and defense[nil] is throwing an error.